# Using AWS S3 API with react native

Tags: amazon-web-services, reactjs, amazon-s3, react-native

I am studying React Native, I played with AWS S3 before, I have set some images in my buckets, I want to do a GET, from my code, and that images are set to private.

I want to call S3 API using the React Native way just like I did on my Angular2 Project. I checked online, only found that there are third party plugin used for upload images to S3.

How would I be able to create a new S3 object in react native`var s3 = new AWS.S3();` and call a function like `s3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});` or simply get a private image on my bucket.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'll start looking into this as I am also curious. I would start with asking, do you know how to make any type of server side logic/requests?  Just because it is React-Native, doesn't mean that you don't have a server that is there to communicate with your app. It seems like your server would do this request.  However, if you want to do this all Client based, and all in React Native, please let me know.

Comment: @JimFactor Thanks, I am just start building this app, I want to load the images when user open the app, it reads the image from S3 directly from my code init function. I do know how to make server side requests in other language.

Comment: have you had any success in finding the solution to this question ?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is now provided in the new AWS Amplify library on the AWS official repo: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

You can use the storage module: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/storage_guide.md

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'
Storage.configure( { level: 'private' } );
Storage.get('myfile.gif');
```

This is an example of a private image but you can do more with the library. It will also use credentials for the user in Authenticated or UnAuthenticated state from the `Auth` module which integrates with Amazon Cognito.

Comment: Can the Storage list all items from a bucket instead of pointing to a specific single item as in your code?